# mysql add duplicated field id to a current field

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i have table like :

```
id     IP     Subnet    Duplicates   Valid
1      foo    16                      1
2      bar    24                      1
3      foo    28                      1
4      foo    32                      1
```

i want update description with id of duplicated row . something like:

```
id     IP    Subnet    Duplicates      Valid
1      foo   16         3,4            0
2      bar   24                        1
3      foo   28         1,4            0
4      foo   32         1,3            0
```

Here is my query :

```
update tblSample inner join (
          select
            t1.Id,
            group_concat(t2.Id) dups
          from
            tblSample t1 inner join tblSample t2
            on t1.Id<>t2.Id ) AND
             ((t1.IP >> (32-LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet))
                << (32-LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet))
             = 
             ((t2.IP >> (32-LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet)) 
                << 32-LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet)))
          group by
            t1.Id
          ) s on tblSample.Id = s.Id
        set
          Valid=0 ,Duplicates=dups
```

my code works but its very slow ( about 53 second for 10000 record )

How can i improve speed ?
is there any way that i can decrease comparison operation.

Comment: It might not be the solution but you can use EXPLAIN statement of MYSQL to trace how your query is executed. It should help you build more efficient query with joins..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without self join in your sub query, maybe will not improve performance greatly, but try it, and also, try to explain it and yours.

```
update tblSample t1
join (
    select name, group_concat(id order by id) as description
    from tblSample
    group by name
) t2
on t1.name = t2.name and cast(t1.id as char) <> t2.description
set t1.description = replace(
                        replace(
                           replace(
                             t2.description,
                             concat(',', t1.id, ','),
                             ',')
                           , concat(',', t1.id)
                           , '')
                        , concat(t1.id, ',')
                        , '')
;
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f65343/1)

Comment: thanks for responding . your query has better speed in simple comparison but my comparison is complicated ( check overlapping ip networks  ) for check overlapping i must do this comarison : `(t1.IP >> (32- LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet) ) <<  (32- LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet) )  )`= (t2.IP >> (32- LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet) ) <<  (32- LEAST(t1.Subnet,t2.Subnet) ) ) `     it means i need t1 fields in group by section

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this query for test:

```
UPDATE dupli d
SET description = (
  SELECT CONCAT('duplicate in ',GROUP_CONCAT(`id` ORDER BY id)) 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM dupli) AS d1  
  WHERE `name` = d.`name` AND id <> d.id ) ;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> UPDATE dupli d
    -> SET description = (
    ->   SELECT CONCAT('duplicate in ',GROUP_CONCAT(`id` ORDER BY id))
    ->   FROM (SELECT * FROM dupli) AS d1
    ->   WHERE `name` = d.`name` AND id <> d.id ) ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from dupli;
+----+------+------------------+
| id | name | description      |
+----+------+------------------+
|  1 | foo  | duplicate in 3,4 |
|  2 | bar  | NULL             |
|  3 | foo  | duplicate in 1,4 |
|  4 | foo  | duplicate in 1,3 |
+----+------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: tnx for responding , this code still has same problem

Comment: if you use MariaDB you can also use EXPLAIN for UPDATE to see which index are missed